# Как задать сырой SQLite запрос через rawQuery в CursorLoader

Tags: android, sqlite

В приложении доступ к базе данных осуществляется через CursorLoader и ContentProvider. Курсор с данными создается в методе:

```
public Loader onCreateLoader( int id, Bundle args )
    {
        Loader cur;
        cur = new CursorLoader( this,
                                           ContractClass.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                           ContractClass.Data.DEFAULT_PROJECTION,
                                           null,
                                           null,
                                           null)
        return cur;
}
```

Необходимо создать запрос к базе на соединение двух таблиц. Как я понял, такой запрос можно выполнить только с помощью rawQuery();
Тут некоторые сложности. Не понимаю, как мне выполнить сырой запрос через лоадер. Вообще изначально в приложении доступ к базе производился через наследников AsyncTask, потом мне посоветовали использовать ContentProvider. Приложение было переписано под него и с этого момента начались все трудности, вообще не понимаю, для чего его использовать если базу приложения не нужно расшаривать. Может лучше откатить обратно, пока не поздно?

Comment: ContentProvider у вас как реализован? По идее в нем вы обрабатываете запросы лоадера, в нем и надо делать rawQuery.

Comment: @xkor В ContentProvider переопределен метод query и через него происходят все запросы. Но я как понял. CursorLoader вызывает этот метод при создании самого CursorLoader с параметрами, переданными через конструктор. Я не могу понять, как уложить запрос с несколькими таблицами и фразой JOIN ON в параметры конструктора CursorLoader(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder), а позже его обработать в переопределенном методе query унаследованном от ContentProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с ContentProvider и CursorLoader вы должны придумать для каждого запроса uri в по которому можно будет отличить этот uri от uri для других запросов и в котором будут все необходимые для запроса параметры. Далее в методе query вашего ContentProvider парсите uri, определяете что за запрос надо выполнить, какие у него параметры и исходя из этого строите SQL запрос, ну и выполняете его.

Comment: Если запрос строится динамически на основе введенных пользователем данных, нужно будет выдумать схему, которая будет зашифровывать запрос в uri, после этого передавать его и дальше парсить нужные параметры и в зависимости от запроса в методе query ContentProvider'a вызывать соответствующий метод класса SQLiteDatabase - rawQuery, query или еще какой-нибудь? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: ну что то типа того